# Passing session user data into a form to edit in react using nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-state

I have the following form,

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { FormProvider, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/client';

// components
import ErrorsPopup from '@/components/ErrorsPopup';
import FormField from '@/components/Forms/FormField';
import Button from '@/components/Button';

const Profile = () => {
  const methods = useForm();
  const { handleSubmit, register } = methods;

  const [session, loading] = useSession();

  // default field states
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Ellis Development - My Profile</title>
      </Head>

      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center w-full">
        <h1 className="text-4xl font-extrabold text-grey-800">
          Profile {session?.firstname} {session?.lastname}
        </h1>

        {/* Form */}
        <FormProvider {...methods}>
          {/* errors */}
          <ErrorsPopup />

          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="flex flex-col gap-y-6 sm:gap-x-8 mt-8">
            {/* first name field */}
            <FormField
              {...register('firstname', {
                required: 'First name is required'
              })}
              name="firstname"
              label="First name"
              value={session?.firstname}
              onChange={(event) => setFirstName(event.target.value)}
              required
              disabled
            />

            {/* last name field */}
            <FormField
              {...register('lastname', {
                required: 'Last name is required'
              })}
              name="lastname"
              label="Last name"
              value={session?.lastname}
              onChange={(event) => setLastName(event.target.value)}
              required
              disabled
            />

            {/* username field */}
            <FormField
              {...register('username', {
                required: 'Username is required'
              })}
              name="username"
              label="Username"
              value={session?.username}
              onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}
              required
              disabled
            />

            {/* password field */}
            <FormField
              {...register('email', {
                required: 'Email is required'
              })}
              type="email"
              name="email"
              label="Email"
              value={session?.email}
              onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
              required
              disabled
            />

            <div className="flex">
              <Button type="submit" label="Save" icon="SaveIcon" />
              <span className="edit_btn">
                <Button type="button" label="Edit" icon="PencilIcon" variant="secondary" />
              </span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </FormProvider>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

I've set state, but and I can click the edit button I can click into the form field but I can't actually edit the data, I'm not sure if I've set something up wrong or is there a way to pass the data into the state itself?

I can confirm the data is showing in the alert when I submit the form but I can't actually edit any of the data.

Comment: That's because you're using the `session.*` values in `FormField`, you need to use state variables instead so that the state changes get reflected in the field's values.

Comment: How do I go about passing the session values within state? @juliomalves

Comment: You can assign the state variables (`firstName`, `lastName`, etc.) to the session values inside a `useEffect`.

Comment: Can you provide an example @juliomalves? Still new to this haha so best to learn by example.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass initial to data to the `useForm`
you can pass session as default value or reset it

add useEffect to reset to reset form with session if exist

```
...
useEffect(()=>{
   //reset form with session values if session exist
   if(session){
      methods.reset(session)
   }
},[])
...
```

Comment: I'm not trying to reset the data I'm trying to allow the user to edit the existing data. However, when I go to edit I can't backspace any field content to therefore allow the user to edit there content.

Answer (score 0):

```
value={session?.firstname}
```

Change this to

```
defaultValue={session?.firstname}
```

Comment: Why? How would that change the behaviour? Why would that help to solve the problem?